# what is the maximum size of temporary folder in Operating Systems?

Tags: windows

Is there any limitation in temporary folder size in Operating systems like XP, 2003, 2008, Vista and Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limitation on the size of the temporary folder in Windows.

You are only limited by the overall amount of free disk space that you have.